# How to return the names of $_GET variables in a url php

Tags: php, url, get

I want to save the name of all the $_GET variables in a url, but im not sure where to start, or finish for that matter.

For example:

if i have:

`url: test.com/forums.php?topic=blog&discussion_id=12`

can i use php to get the name, i.e. "topic" and "discussion_id from the $_GET variables and can i then store the values: "topic" and "discussion_id" in an array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get this by calling [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) on `$_GET`:

```
$getVars = array_keys($_GET);
```

Comment: This will show the variables on the URL that invokes the script, not a URL *within* the script.

Comment: @Ignacio Yes, that's what I assume the question is asking about.  If not, well, mario's given the solution, and I've upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 5):

If this isn't about the *current* URL, but just some *$url string* you want to extract the parameters from then:

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
```

will populate $params with:

```
[topic] => blog
[discussion_id] => 12
```

Comment: +1 And `array_keys` can then be used to get the keys in an array if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to grab data from the URL using GET.  Change it to $_POST will work for post.

```
<?php
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) 
{
        //other code go here
    echo 'Index : ' . $key . ' & Value : ' . $value;
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is usual php-array. you may use it in foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v)
  echo ($k . '=' . $v);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Fetch the elements as you would with any other array.